# Google Drive API - Authorization for Downloads Post 1.70 Beta

Tags: google-drive-api

I updated by Google Drive SDK references to 1.70 recently and updated all of my authentication code from using IAuthorizationState and the NativeApplicationClient to using UserCredentials, Drive.Auth.Store, and a DriveService object consistent with Google's "supported" method.

Everything working with my DriveService is working great.  I can upload files, list files, create files and folders.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to perform the simple act of downloading files by ID and I can't determine how I can leverage my new authentication code to support downloading.  The SDK examples are referencing IAuthenticator but I'm not sure if that is a legacy object and my current project can't naturally reference it (missing a reference or perhaps isn't in 1.70).

I recognize that the Drive SDK may not actually have a method of downloading a file, but I'm very confused about how I can use my clean, new authentication store (Drive.Auth.Store) which has everything I should need to authenticate with the downloading action.

A point in the right direction would be most helpful!  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Should clarify that the download example in the SDK makes sense to me, but I'm not familar with the IAuthenticator object and not sure if there is anything I need or should do to relate my working Auth Store with this object: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

Comment: What do you mean by "downloading files". If you mean the file meta-data, use the files.get stuff. if you mean the contents, then it depends what kind of file it is, but in simple terms, the meta-data object contains either a downloadUrl or a set of exportLinks which are simple URLs you can fetch (with an oauth header)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I mean downloading a file not its metadata.  I've figured out how to use my auth store in this case to retrieve the access token and form it into a http request with the token in the header.  Will post back results.  Your response has at least validated that I should be just initiating a simple httprequest against the downloadUrl passing in the access token.